# Reactjs AntD Select - how to render values only on button click

Tags: reactjs, antd

I have an AntD select and button components.

I want the selected values in the select component to only render when the Add Item button is clicked (right now the update is triggered by onChange prop of the Select component).

Right now I cannot seem to figure out how to update values from handleUpdateValues

```
import React, {useState } from "react";
import { Select, Button } from "antd";
import { PlusOutlined } from '@ant-design/icons';


export const AntdSelect = () => {
    const [items, setItems] = useState([
        {
            value: "Jack",
            label: "Jack (100)",
        },
        {
            value: "Lucy",
            label: "Lucy (101)",
        },
    ]);
    const [values, setValues] = useState([]);
    const [selectedValues, setSelectedValues] = useState([]);

    const handleUpdateValues = () => {
        console.log(selectedValues);

    };
    const handleChange = (value) => {
        setSelectedValues(value);
    };

    return (
        <>
            <Select
                mode="multiple"
                allowClear
                labelInValue
                style={{
                    width: 500,
                }}
                placeholder="custom dropdown render"
                onChange={handleChange}
                value={values}
                options={items}
            />
            <Button
                type="text"
                icon={<PlusOutlined />}
                onClick={handleUpdateValues}
            >
                Add item
            </Button>
        </>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `items` state, needs to be an empty array initially. In the `handleUpdateValues` you should update the `setItems` with the actual array with the values.

Edit: updated the sandbox to include your comment.

example [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/basic-usage-antd-5-1-2-forked-fcv6iq?file=/demo.tsx)

Comment: thanks for taking a look and providing feedback! I think I did not explain myself well. Initially Jack and Lucy should appear in the options, but if I click on Lucy, the value should only be displayed in the Select component after I click add item. Nothing should be displayed till I hit Add Item

Comment: I update the sandbox. Have a look

Comment: Is this what you wanted?

Comment: yes! Huge help!